# Can't mount a multipath LUN

Tags: debian, mount, multipath-storage

I'm trying to mount a lun, it's visible in multipath -ll and I can see the multiple access to it with lsblk. I know screw up somewhere along the line because sda isn't visibly mounted in lsblk anymore and i can't find where.
Thank you in advance.

```
    root@debian:~# multipath -ll
mpathb (3600508b1001037383941424344450500) dm-0 HP,LOGICAL VOLUME
size=68G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active
  `- 3:0:0:0 sda 8:0  active ready running
mpatha (3600601601ad126004652c478fd40e511) dm-1 DGC,VRAID
size=500G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 emc' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=4 status=active
| |- 2:0:0:0 sdb 8:16 active ready running
| `- 4:0:1:0 sde 8:64 active ready running
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  |- 2:0:1:0 sdc 8:32 active ready running
  `- 4:0:0:0 sdd 8:48 active ready running
root@debian:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 68.3G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 1007K  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0  127M  0 part
└─sda3   8:3    0 68.2G  0 part
sdb      8:16   0  500G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0  244G  0 part
└─sdb2   8:18   0  256G  0 part
sdc      8:32   0  500G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0  244G  0 part
└─sdc2   8:34   0  256G  0 part
sdd      8:48   0  500G  0 disk
├─sdd1   8:49   0  244G  0 part
└─sdd2   8:50   0  256G  0 part
sde      8:64   0  500G  0 disk
├─sde1   8:65   0  244G  0 part
└─sde2   8:66   0  256G  0 part
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Please show the `mount` command you did and the error message.

Comment: root@debian:~# mount /dev/sdb /disk
mount: /dev/sdb is already mounted or /disk busy

Comment: "because sda isn't visibly mounted" - er, sda shows in the output you provided, and its a partitioned disk. There's only one path to this (OTOH You didn't say what you were trying to mount). According to what you've shown us this host has no mounted volumes - so where is '/'?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mount `/dev/sdb`, because it is part of a multipath map, thus considered "busy". You can use `/dev/mapper/mpatha` instead, but you probably don't want that, because the underlying devices are partitioned. So create the partition devices first (unless they are present already) and mount those:

```
# kpartx -avp-part /dev/mapper/mpatha
# mount /dev/mapper/mpatha-part1 /disk
```

Answer (score 0):

`lsblk` is using `/proc/$$/mountinfo` .

```
strace lsblk 2>&1 | grep /proc
open("/proc/self/mountinfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
lstat("/proc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc/self", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self", "755", 4095)     = 3
lstat("/proc/755", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc/755/mountinfo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/proc/swaps", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9
```

Perhaps `/proc` is not mounted (`ls /proc` to check).

**EDIT**

As `/proc` is mounted  `grep /dev/sd /proc/$$/mountinfo` to check what sd device is mounted.

Comment: `ls /proc` returns a lot of things, so i guess it's mounted

Comment: `grep /dev/sd /proc/$$/mountinfo` returns nothing